# VBScript: Workbooks.Open - without opening the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

This Code saves an xlsx file from one folder to a different folder with a password and then deletes the original.

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

strTodays_Date = Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2)

If fso.FileExists("\\ServerPath\Test\Test_Input\Test1.xlsx") Then
   Set obj1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\\ServerPath\Test\Test_Input\Test1.xlsx")
   objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
   obj1.SaveAs "\\ServerPath\Test\Test_Output\Test1" & "_" & strTodays_Date & ".xlsx",,"123098"
   obj1.Close False
   fso.DeleteFile("\\ServerPath\Test\Test_Input\Test1.xlsx")
End If

Set obj1    = Nothing 
Set objExcel    = Nothing
Set fso     = Nothing
```

When I run this vbscript on my local machine, it runs as I expect - without the password protected spreadsheet actually opening during the process.

When I run this on a different server [where the completed code will eventually have to run], it opens the newly-created password protected spreadsheet and waits for me to enter the password before completing the save as process and deleting the original.

How can I prevent the spreadsheet from opening, requiring the password and interrupting the process?

Thanks!

Comment: Please try this: `strTodays_Date = Format(Date, "yymmdd")`

Comment: The reason for the different behaviour might be in a different version of Excel being used. Even if you would tell us the version[s] being used we wouldn't likely be able to replicate your test. Therefore please excuse the guessing. My guess is that the password is being asked because the protected sheet is active. Try saving the file with another sheet being the active one. I don't believe adding the password to the `Workbooks.Open` command might help but I would try it nevertheless. Next, I would approach the problem from the view that it makes sense not to allow you to do what you intend,

Comment: ... while you don't know the password. That leads me to look at folder permissions (an off-chance) and the obvious: remove the protection before moving the file.

Comment: @Variatus: Thanks so much. I don't want to change the format of strTodays_Date. I want it to be "yyyymmdd" and that art of my code is not in question. I will try your other suggestions. I don't believe removing server permissions is an option. Thanks again!

Comment: How do I save the file with another sheet being the active one?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this but it wasn't till I dug deeper that I realized what the problem was.
While testing, I had inadvertently copied a password protected file into the 'Test_Input' folder. As a result, this line of Code:

Set obj1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("\ServerPath\Test\Test_Input\Test1.xlsx")

was actually trying to open a previously password-protected file.
Once I realized that and corrected it, the code worked fine.

Again, please accept my apologies!